# Deciding between a Shared Folder and a Package for Shared Logic in Clean Architecture

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, clean-architecture

In the context of Clean Architecture, I'm wondering about the best approach for organizing shared logic within an application. Should I create a shared folder where I'll place components, modules, or utilities used throughout the entire application, or would it be more appropriate to create a dedicated package specifically for the shared logic?

I understand that Clean Architecture emphasizes the separation of concerns and maintaining a clear boundary between layers. However, I'm uncertain about the most effective way to handle shared code. Here are some specific points I'd like to explore:

- What are the pros and cons of using a shared folder to store components that are utilized across multiple layers of Clean Architecture?
- Alternatively, what are the advantages and disadvantages of creating a dedicated package to encapsulate shared logic in Clean Architecture?
- Are there any architectural considerations or potential pitfalls associated with either approach?
- How does each approach affect code organization, modularity, and maintainability in the long run?
- Are there any established best practices or industry standards regarding this topic within the context of Clean Architecture?
- Does the choice between a shared folder and a dedicated package depend on the scale or complexity of the application?
- Are there any real-world examples or case studies where one approach has proven to be more effective than the other?

**Example:**

There is an authentication feature in the application that contains functionalities:
1. login
2. register
3. logout
4. user authentication status
Login and register should be used only on their deducated screens, but logout action and user authentication status should be accessable from entire application. In this situation, should I use shared folder which will conatin code for logout functionality and state about current user authentication status or it is better to create local (private) package for this parts of the logic which should be shared.

I got idea for approach where shared logic is separated into packeges from this [BLoC login example](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterlogintutorial?id=project-setup).

In the example I mentioned before, they used the BLoC pattern, where the repository is separated into its own package, but the BLoC definition is still created in the lib directory. So in clean architecture, I assume that everything connected to authentication (in this example) should be in the package except use cases, DTOs and BLoCs that are specifically connected to the login and register actions.

I'm keen to hear from experienced developers who have encountered similar scenarios and can provide insights or recommendations based on their experiences. Thank you!